# .exit().remove() appears to remove text but not rectangle in line chart legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart built with D3. When a user selects an option from the dropdown, the chart updates.

The legend has checkboxes filled with colors matching the lines on the chart, along with text indicating the country the line and checkbox represent.

Here's my problem. For the product 'soy', Hong Kong has no data. When I change the dropdown selection to 'soy', the text for Hong Kong is removed from the legend. However the checkbox is not. Further, the country below (Canada) moves up, which makes the legend incorrect.

I think this is an issue related to .exit().remove(), but I can't figure out what's happening. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ctj17giFFYw4y2eZbOX8?p=preview)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    #legendContainer{
        position:absolute;
        top:60px;
        left:10px;
        overflow: auto;
        height:490px;
        width:150px;
    }
    #legend{
        width:130px;
        height:200px;
    }
    .legend {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-anchor: left;
    }
    .legendcheckbox{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #showAll{
        position:absolute;
        top:600px;
        left:880px;
    }
    #clearAll{
        position:absolute;
        top:600px;
        left:950px;
    }
    input{
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:#999;
        border:0;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #inds{
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        left:10px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <select id="inds">
            <option value="corn" selected="selected">corn</option>
            <option value="soy">soy</option>
            <option value="grain">grain</option>
    </select>
    <div id="legendContainer" class="legendContainer">
        <svg id="legend"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="showAll">
        <input name="showAllButton"
         type="button"
         value="Show All"
         onclick="showAll()" />
    </div>
    <div id="clearAll">
        <input name="clearAllButton"
         type="button"
         value="Clear All"
         onclick="clearAll()" />
    </div>
    <script>

    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
      var result = [];
      json.forEach(function(val,idx,arr){
        if(val[key] == value){

          result.push(val)
        }
      })
      return result;
    }

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 200},
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var countryline = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var data;
    // Get the data
    d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {

      json.forEach(function(d) {
            d.value = +d.value;
      });

        d3.select('#inds')
                .on("change", function () {
                    var sect = document.getElementById("inds");
                    var section = sect.options[sect.selectedIndex].value;


                    data = filterJSON(json, 'product', section);

                    data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.value = +d.value;
                    d.year = parseDate(String(d.year));
                    d.active = true;
                });

                    updateGraph(data);
                });

                // generate initial graph
                data = filterJSON(json, 'product', 'corn');
                updateGraph(data);

    });

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["limegreen", "orange", "purple"]);

    function updateGraph(data) {

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        // Nest the entries by country
        dataNest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.country;})
            .entries(data);

            var result = dataNest.filter(function(val,idx, arr){
                      return $("." + val.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')).attr("fill") != "#ccc" 
                      // matching the data with selector status
                    })

            var country = svg.selectAll(".line")
                  .data(result, function(d){return d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')});

            country.enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "line");

            country.transition()
                .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')); })
                .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '');}) // assign ID
                .attr("d", function(d){
                    return countryline(d.values)
                });

            country.exit().remove();

            var legend = d3.select("#legend")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(dataNest);

                //checkboxes
                legend.enter().append("rect")
                  .attr("width", 10)
                  .attr("height", 10)
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 0 +i*15; })  // spacing
                  .attr("fill",function(d) { 
                    return color(d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, ''));

                  })
                  .attr("class", function(d,i){return "legendcheckbox " + d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')})
                    .on("click", function(d){
                      d.active = !d.active;

                      d3.select(this).attr("fill", function(d){
                        if(d3.select(this).attr("fill")  == "#ccc"){
                          return color(d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, ''));
                        }else {
                          return "#ccc";
                        }
                      })


                     var result = dataNest.filter(function(val,idx, arr){
                 return $("." + val.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')).attr("fill") != "#ccc" 
               // matching the data with selector status
              })

               // Hide or show the lines based on the ID
               svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d){return d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')})
                 .enter()
                 .append("path")
                 .attr("class", "line")
                 .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')); })
                .attr("d", function(d){
                        return countryline(d.values);
                 });

              svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d){return d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')}).exit().remove()  

                    })

        // Add the Legend text
        legend.enter().append("text")
          .attr("x", 15)
          .attr("y", function(d,i){return 10 +i*15;})
          .attr("class", "legend");

            legend.transition()
          .style("fill", "#777" )
          .text(function(d){return d.key;});

            legend.exit().remove();

            svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
    };

    function clearAll(){
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(100)
                .attr("d", function(d){
            return null;
          });
      d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
      .transition().duration(100)
          .attr("fill", "#ccc");
    };

    function showAll(){
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(100)
                .attr("d", function(d){
            return countryline(d.values);
          });
      d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
      .attr("fill",function(d) {
        if (d.active == true){
           return color(d.key.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, ''));
         }
       })
    };

    </script>
    </body>
```

Data:

```
[
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"131"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"231"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"191"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"302"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"31"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"331"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"291"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"250"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"11"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"230"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"185"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"corn",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"310"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"171"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"121"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"231"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"202"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"146"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"130"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"195"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"soy",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"210"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"71"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"221"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"31"
    },
    {
      "country":"Côte d'Ivoire",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"102"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"173"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"194"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"195"
    },
    {
      "country":"Hong Kong, China",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"230"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"216"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"184"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"125"
    },
    {
      "country":"Canada",
      "product":"grain",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"150"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ask yourself, what composes each piece of a legend?  It's a `text` and `rect` elements, so, we should probably group them and handle their entering, updating and exiting as one.  Second, now that we have a group, what happens in each of the enter, update and exit scenarios...

```
// find me all the things classed with legendGroup
// if you are selecting by element type with d3 
// you are usually asking for trouble
var legendGroups = d3.select("#legend")
  .selectAll(".legendGroup")
  .data(dataNest, function(d){
    return d.key; // always try and use a key function to uniquely identify
  });

// let's handle the enter situation
// we are going to append a `g` to hold our rect and text for each piece of the legend
// note we assign this to a variable for later use
var enterGroups = legendGroups
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","legendGroup"); // remember to class it, so we can selectAll it later

// exit scenerio
// this is easy, it'll remove the whole group, both rect and text
legendGroups
  .exit()
  .remove();

// update scenerio
// if the element is not added or removed, we really just change it's position
legendGroups
  .attr("transform",function(d,i){
     return "translate(10," + (10 + i* 15) + ")"; // position the whole group
   });

// finally let's set up our legend items...
// Add the Legend text
enterGroups.append("text")
  .text(function(d){return d.key;})
  .attr("x", 10);

enterGroups
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. The commented code is great. It makes sense now.